# 2-d Char array in C Unexpected output

Tags: c, arrays, char, 2d

I have this Piece of COde that store a string in a 2-d char array.IN my code i am using a 2x6 
2-D char array.On providing a 12digit string LIKE > "COMEHOMEARUN". It should store it as
C O M E H O
M E A R U N
but I am getting the output as
C O M E H M
M E A R U N   ...i.e the value at [0]6] automatically gets the value of [1][0].

here's the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char string[20];
    char aray[1][5];
    int i,j,k=0;
    gets(string);
    //storing the individual characters in the string in the form of 2x6 char array
    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
        {
            aray[i][j]=string[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    //displaying the array Generated
    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", aray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In a C array declaration like `char array[N][M]`, the `N` and `M` values are **not** "the highest valid index"; they mean "the number of values".

So your declaration

```
char aray[1][5];
```

defines an array sized 1x5, *not* 2x6 as you intend.

You need:

```
char aray[2][6];
```

But of course, the actual indexing is 0-based so for `char aray[2][6]`, the "last" element is at `aray[1][5]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing `char aray[1][5]` to `char aray[2][6]`

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing is not correct.

When you declare any char array you have to give sufficient length. In your code you give the dimension 1 but it required 2.

Declare the array as:

```
   char array[2][6];
```

That will work.